# Help replacing electrical switch

Tags: electrical

I’m replacing a single switch with a dimmable switch.  I’ve turned offthe power.  The current box has 2 black wires, one of which does not appear to be attached to anything.  I’ll try to attack a picture.

I’m assuming the wires are

Black (in switch) carries power.
Red (in switch) returns power.
Plain brass (in switch) ground
Loose black?

Any help appreciated.

Edit,  I’m a moron.  When in doubt read the instructions.  Another switch also controls these lights, so the second black is for that.

Comment: Black should not be used for a ground , is it a metal box? If metal and no green or bare wire it may be grounded through the conduit.

Comment: That's a 3-way switch setup, then.  You have to pay very close attention to screw colors (black=common) or markings, *and completly disregard the position of terminals on the switch*.   My preference is to mark the travelers (wires to brass screws) with yellow tape.  Travelers can be swapped without problem so they can be marked the same color.   Note travelers  are always in the same cable.

Comment: Your photo did not post...